# Fixing garden building floor

Tags: floor

I have a "summer house" in the garden, it's been there years, but the floor has started to fail/rot - I managed to put my foot through it!

I plan to remove the carpet tiles, treat the existing floor boards with anti-rot stuff, and then put additional flooring over the top to give new stability.

Is this a good idea? What new flooring would be the best value option? I've been looking at P5 T&G chipboard, regular chipboard, plywood, etc.

Comment: What is the base underneath the floor? Concrete? Pressure treated wood? Something else? If existing boards are actually rotting then they need to be replaced, not just treated.

Comment: There are "joists" of (what I assume is) pressure-treated wood, which sit directly on a concrete base. Then the floor is (again, what I assume is) pressure-treated wood boards on top. The "joists" are fine, just a couple of the boards are rotted a bit. I've replaced the section I put my foot through, but there are a couple of other weak-feeling sections, so I'm hoping to shore the whole thing up.

Comment: Best bet is going to be replace more rather than less. I know it costs more now, but since you have an additional covering (carpet, unlike a deck that is typically open), damage will be hidden and you won't see the progression until it gets really bad again.